# Java Generics with inheritance and covariance

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, covariance

I'm having a bit of a hard time to understand how to correctly use covariance and wildcards when using generics in Java.

I'm trying to avoid having to use casting.

Here's my situation :

```
class Element {}

class ChildElement extends Element {}

interface A<T> {
    T doSomething(T foo);
}

interface B extends A<Element> {}

interface C extends B {}

class D implements B {

    @Override
    public Element doSomething(Element foo) {} 
}

class E extends D implements C {
    @Override
    public Element doSomething(Element foo) {}
}
```

This situation works, but I would like to be able to do this instead for class E :

```
class E extends D implements C {

    @Override
    public ChildElement doSomething(ChildEment foo) {}
}
```

From what I've seen, what I want to do is covariance, but I can't do it in the current sitution as I need to use wildcards. But I've read that you can't do covariance with generics and wildcards.

Is there any solution to this problem ? I'd like to keep the strong dependencies between each classes.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Unless you implement `A<ChildElement>` instead of `A<Element>`, there is no way this can work.

Comment: That's what I thought.. So I need to break a dependency in any case ?

Comment: If a class implements B (even if indirectly via C), then it MUST allow A<Element>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make `B` generic, but you can put a bound on the generic parameter such that it's at least an `Element`:

```
interface B<T extends Element> extends A<T> {}

interface C<T extends Element> extends B<T> {}
```

Then about the closest you can get is:

```
 class D<T extends Element> implements B<T> {
    @Override
    public T doSomething(T foo) { return null;}
}

class E extends D<ChildElement> implements C<ChildElement> {
    @Override
    public ChildElement doSomething(ChildElement foo) { return null;}
}
```

which compiles.

Comment: Wow that's great ! Exactly what I needed, thanks a lot, I was slightly lost with all the rules surrounding generics in Java. So basically what we are doing here is using generics with bounds instead of a simple parameter to enable ChildElement in classe E ?

Comment: Yes - the bound captures the notion that the interface subclasses B and C should only be applied to a class/subclass of Element, but defers specification to the concrete class. FYI, covariance only comes in to play when overriding a method whose signature includes the type of the class itself - then you may override using the type of the subclass. It doesn't apply to generic parameters though.

Answer (score 1):

> But I've read that you can't do covariance with generics and
>   wildcards.

This statement is not about covariant return type, but it means that you can't do this:

```
List<Number> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
l1 = l2; //illegal
```

But T it's also any subclass of T. So thing like this:

```
interface Interface<T> {
    T method();
}

class SomeClass implements Interface<Number>{
    @Override
    public Float method() {
        return 1F;
    }
}
```

works fine. But method's signature of subclass(implementation) and superclass(interface) must matches. So in your example

```
class E extends D implements C {

    @Override
    public ChildElement doSomething(ChildEment foo) {}
}
```

it's illegal.

Comment: So it would be legal to return ChildElement, but not have ChildElement as a substitute of Element in the method parameter in E ?

Comment: @Hawknight yes, this's constraints of _overriding_, method's signature must matches, but _covariant return type_ is allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So covariance is only accepted in Java as covariance return type !

Comment: @Hawknight actually covariance means that if `Superclass` is superclass and `Subclass` is subclass then using _is-a_ relation you can refer to `Subclass` object by reference to `Superclass` object : `Superclass obj = new Subclass();` ([see also).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) The same is also true for arrays. But with generics it isn't true : `List` of `Number`-s **is not a** `List` of `Integer`-s as in example above.

Answer (score 1):

The interface you've described can't be covariant. What would you want/expect to happen with this code?

```
class OtherElement extends Element{}
Element oe = new OtherElement();
E e = new E();
B b = e;
b.doSomething(oe);
```

This compiles correctly, as it must - but if `E#doSomething` expected a `ChildElement` we would have a failure here.